# How to separate database information per user in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, database-design

I am looking for a solution to the problem that I will have many different users creating/signing into my web application that uses Rails, but the current application returns the same data from the database regardless of which user created/modified the data.

Is there a way that I can separate the information/data created and modified on a per user basis?

I found the following stackoverflow question that seems to be related to my issue, but was unsure if it would solve my problem and/or how to implement it. 
[Rails - Separate Database per Subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602901/rails-separate-database-per-subdomain)

Thanks.

Comment: where is the stackoverflow question ?

Comment: I updated it - so sorry about that!

Comment: By different users you mean different kind of users or just different users. share your db schema it would be easy to propose a better solution

Comment: I mean just different users. From what I've found I think the best solution looks like using the Apartment gem with postgresql. At the moment I'm just using the built in spite database

Comment: Actually if you don't have any user categories or roles then simple db design will make you achieve this.

Comment: Sorry this is late, I ended up using CanCan to describe two roles, admin and regular user and do it that way and it seems to work. Unfortunately, I don't know what simple db design is possible to achieve this otherwise. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are looking for a way to implement multi tenancy in your application.
If that is in fact what you are looking for then you could take a look at the following two videos that use default_scope:

1. [General idea behind multitenancy and default_scopes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwILy2GB7XE)
2. [Multi tenancy with PostgreSQL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBbFC7fD6MI)

Alternatively you could check out [the apartment gem](https://github.com/influitive/apartment)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the gem named "Acts as tenant", simple and easy to implement.
https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant